# MVC 3 web application storing user_id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is a a topic with a variety of opinions around the web.

Basically i am developing a SAAS application using ASP.net MVC 3.

I wanted to know what would be a good way of storing user_id to see if the correct user is authenticated?

I know the classic session asp.net method but really want to avoid this.

Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you can Authorize the users simply in the controller method. There you can authenticate an individual user/s or group/s.

If you are using ASP.NET Membership provider,

Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

This will work. Please comment if you need any other guidance.